# Unknown format in R, how to convert it into rows and columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I scraped something from the web that gives me something like this:

```
[1] "(Wirtschaft, 00:00)"       "(Kultur, 23:42)"           "(Sport, 23:38)"            "(Politik, 23:16)"         
  [5] "(Sport, 22:29)"            "(Panorama, 21:56)"         "(Sport, 21:39)"            "(Sport, 21:25)"           
  [9] "(Sport, 20:23)"            "(Politik, 20:21)"          "(Politik, 20:09)"          "(Wissenschaft, 19:41)"    
 [13] "(Politik, 18:43)"          "(Sport, 18:16)"            "(Politik, 17:53)"          "(Wirtschaft, 17:41)"      
 [17] "(Politik, 17:37)"          "(Sport, 17:28)"            "(Sport, 17:09)"            "(Sport, 17:07)"
```

What I am wondering now is the following. How is R seeing this? I simply want to have observations(rows) and variables(columns) now. However, when I use ncol() or nrow() it shows NULL. Can someone tell me how I can manipulate the date so that I have rows and columns. I know there is the separate function and all that but everybody explains it so difficult that you need 5 years experience to understand it. Please help a beginner to learn. Thanks

Comment: It is a `vector` which doesn't have dimensions.  So `nrow` or `ncol` returns NULL.  If you need to convert it to `matrix` ie. `matrix(yourvector)`, it results in dimensions of 1 column with number of rows equal to length of yourvector.  The `separate` from `tidyr` is to separate or split the string into substrings in two columns, where the first column will have words like 'Sport', 'Kultur' and second column with '00:00', '23:42'.  I hope it doesn't need 5 years exp

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be with following steps:

```
# Data
v <- c("(Wirtschaft, 00:00)", "(Kultur, 23:42)", "(Sport, 23:38)","(Politik, 23:16)",
 "(Sport, 22:29)","(Panorama, 21:56)","(Sport, 21:39)", "(Sport, 21:25)",
 "(Sport, 20:23)","(Politik, 20:21)","(Politik, 20:09)",
 "(Wissenschaft, 19:41)","(Politik, 18:43)")  

# Solution
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x <- gsub("\\(|\\)", "", v, perl = T) %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(x) <- "Heading"
separate(x, "Heading", c("Item", "Time"), sep = ",")

           Item   Time
1    Wirtschaft  00:00
2        Kultur  23:42
3         Sport  23:38
4       Politik  23:16
5         Sport  22:29
6      Panorama  21:56
7         Sport  21:39
8         Sport  21:25
9         Sport  20:23
10      Politik  20:21
11      Politik  20:09
12 Wissenschaft  19:41
```

Comment: That is absolutely great. Thank you so much. However, when I now look at view(x), I still do find all of the observations in the same column, I am wondering why it is like this? Can you explain this?

Comment: @Space_Roger You should assigned the output to a new `df`. Something like `df_final <- separate(x, "Heading", c("Item", "Time"), sep = ",")`. Then `df_final` will store the result.

Comment: Can you explain what you did in this function gsub("\\(|\\)", "", v, perl = T), what does "\\(|\\)" mean in this case. Its really hilarious, there is no way to understand except for asking here... Would be really grateful.

Comment: @Space_Roger `\(|\)` means try to match `(` or `)` and if found replace with 2nd parameter of `gsub` that is "" means remove `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to transform the vector of strings you've shown into a `data.frame`, a structure with rows and columns:

```
# Your current vector
scraped <- c("(Wirtschaft, 00:00)", "(Kultur, 23:42)", "(Sport, 23:38)", "(Politik, 23:16)")
```

Here I've just recreated a sample of your data, here it is:

```
> scraped
[1] "(Wirtschaft, 00:00)" "(Kultur, 23:42)"    
[3] "(Sport, 23:38)"      "(Politik, 23:16)"
```

Now I'm creating a function that will remove the brackets and commas from each element in this vector:

```
# Create a function to clean each element of the vector
clean <- function(x) {
  # Replace brackets with blank strings
  no_brackets <- gsub("[()]", "", x)
  # Split the string at the comma
  split <- strsplit(no_brackets, ", ")[[1]]
  return(split)
}
```

You can see how this works on a single element of your vector:

```
> clean(scraped[1])
[1] "Wirtschaft" "00:00"
```

It has taken `"(Wirtschaft, 00:00)"` and separated that one element into two, while removing the brackets and comma.

Next, I apply this function to every element of `scraped` using the function `sapply`:

```
# Apply the clean function to each element of your vector
mat <- sapply(scraped, clean)
```

Now we have a matrix:

```
> mat
     (Wirtschaft, 00:00) (Kultur, 23:42) (Sport, 23:38) (Politik, 23:16)
[1,] "Wirtschaft"        "Kultur"        "Sport"        "Politik"       
[2,] "00:00"             "23:42"         "23:38"        "23:16"
```

So this is now in a rows and columns format. However, it's more common to have variables of the same type in the same column, and each observation illustrated by a row, ie the other way up. It's also more useful to have them in the data structure named a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix`. So in this final step, I will transpose the matrix with the `t` function and convert it to a dataframe with the `data.frame` function:

```
# Transpose the matrix and convert it to a data.frame
df <- data.frame(t(mat), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Now the dataset is a data.frame that looks like this:

```
> df
                            X1    X2
(Wirtschaft, 00:00) Wirtschaft 00:00
(Kultur, 23:42)         Kultur 23:42
(Sport, 23:38)           Sport 23:38
(Politik, 23:16)       Politik 23:16
```

You can access different values in the data.frame with the syntax `df[row, column]`:

```
> df[1, 1]  # The first row and first column of df
[1] "Wirtschaft"
> df[3, 2]  # The third row and second column of df
[1] "23:38"
```